# What causes WriteFile to return error 38 (ERROR_HANDLE_EOF)?

Tags: windows, winapi

What would cause WriteFile to return error 38 (ERROR_HANDLE_EOF, Reached the end of the file)?  The "file" in this case is a mailslot.  The way my program works is I have a process (running as a Windows service) that creates multiple child processes.  Each child opens a mailslot of the same name in order to send status information back to its parent. In my small scale testing this works fine, but I am seeing cases where when I have several processes
running (like 16) I am getting this error.  The code below shows how I am opening and writing to the mailslot in the child process.

Is it perhaps because the parent is not reading the mailslot fast enough?  Is there a way to increase capacity of a mailslot so that end of file never gets reached?  I really don't see how a mailslot can get full anyway, as long 
as there is disk space (which there is plenty of).

```
char gLocalSlotName[256]="\\\\.\\mailslot\\TMAgentSlot-ComputerName";

gAgentSlot = CreateFile(gLocalSlotName, GENERIC_WRITE, FILE_SHARE_READ, (LPSECURITY_ATTRIBUTES) NULL,
                               OPEN_EXISTING, FILE_ATTRIBUTE_NORMAL, (HANDLE) NULL);


fResult = WriteFile(gAgentSlot, (char *)&ProcStat, sizeof(PROCSTAT), &cbWritten, (LPOVERLAPPED) NULL);
if (!fResult) {
  derr = GetLastError();
  printf("WriteFile error=%d", derr);
}
```

Comment: you need call `RtlGetLastNtStatus()` instead of `GetLastError()` - what status will be ? `STATUS_FILE_FORCED_CLOSED` ( `c00000b6`) or `STATUS_END_OF_FILE` (`c0000011`) ?

Comment: really i 100% sure that you got `STATUS_FILE_FORCED_CLOSED` - *The specified file has been closed by another process.* - nothing comon with end of file at all

Comment: IIRC if the server side is closing, the mailslot filesystem forces all clients to the closing state as well and fails requests with `STATUS_FILE_FORCED_CLOSED`, as suggested above.

Comment: BTW, the mailslot and namedpipe filesystems do not use space on disk volumes. These are in-memory filesystems.

Comment: @eryksun - `STATUS_FILE_FORCED_CLOSED` returned by `msfs!MsCommonWrite` if the end in closing state. from another side `STATUS_END_OF_FILE` look like never return by *msfs.sys*. both this ntstatus converted to the same `ERROR_HANDLE_EOF`. the win32 errors is very confused some time. i can not undersyand why mapping ntstatus codes to win32 errors not injective. why at all need map

Comment: @RbMm, if you closed your own handle, it would be an invalid-handle error. In this case, the client-side (CCB) was forced into the closing state by the filesystem because the server-side (FCB) was closed and cleaned up.

Comment: As to mapping errors, the Windows API predates the NT API by many years, and its set of error codes had to be retained and extended for the Windows subsystem. The NTAPI was certainly not public nor intended to be so in the 1990s, except for the limited subset published for drivers. In many cases I think not nearly enough thought went into the decision about when to reuse existing error codes and when to extend with new codes.

Comment: yes, src of error of course - server close mailslot handle. *if you closed your own handle, it would be an invalid-handle error.* must be obvious. and this general error will be returned by I/O subsystem. not by driver

Comment: "*Each child opens a mailslot of the same name in order to send status information back to its parent*" - why are you using mailslots for that, and not pipes instead? [MSDN says](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/ipc/mailslots): "*Named pipes are a simple way for two processes to exchange messages. Mailslots, on the other hand, are a simple way for a process to broadcast messages to multiple processes.*"

Comment: @RemyLebeau, using a mailslot works, though using inbound named-pipe connections would be better. Mailslot broadcasting is a concern. When the target is a domain name or "*" for the primary domain, the redirector broadcasts a mailslot message to every machine in the domain. If messages should only come from local processes, make certain the name is unique to the machine to avoid an accidental name collision with broadcasted messages.

Answer (score 2):

`WriteFile` is thin shell over [`NtWriteFile`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/drivers/ddi/content/ntifs/nf-ntifs-ntwritefile). if `NtWriteFile` return error `NTSTATUS` - it will be converted to its equivalent win32 error code (via [`RtlNtStatusToDosError`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/winternl/nf-winternl-rtlntstatustodoserror)) and `WriteFile` return false. win32 error code you can got via `GetLastError()`. however original `NTSTATUS` you can got via `RtlGetLastNtStatus()` exported by *ntdll.dll* api. problem with win32 errors codes - some time several different `NTSTATUS` values converted to the same win32 error.

in case `ERROR_HANDLE_EOF` - 2 different `NTSTATUS` converted to it:
`STATUS_END_OF_FILE` and `STATUS_FILE_FORCED_CLOSED`. the `STATUS_END_OF_FILE` never (look like) returned by *msfs.sys* (driver which handle mailslots). from another side - `STATUS_FILE_FORCED_CLOSED` (*The specified file has been closed by another process.*) can be returned when you write data to mailslot (by `msfs.MsCommonWrite`) if server end of the mailslot (end which you create via `CreateMailslot` call) already closed.
formally when last server handle was closed - all connecting clients marked as in closing state (inside `MsFsdCleanup`) and then if you call `WriteFile` for such client - the `STATUS_FILE_FORCED_CLOSED` is returned.

so -

> What causes WriteFile to return error 38 (ERROR_HANDLE_EOF)?

the server process by some reason close self mailslot handle. you need search in this direction - when and why you close mailsot handle in parent process